# Removing dynamic time text for time enabled map in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, timeslider, spatio-temporal-data

I recently created a map with time enabled and would like to format the displayed date time in order to show only the date portion of the text.  Currently I'm using the default formatting shown below and getting a complete date/time representation.

[image]

Using the above formatting I get the following result.

[image]

How could I go about editing the formatting to remove the time portion all together and leave only the date?

I have tried changing "time" to "date". which just broke the dynamic expression altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following in your text box:

```
<dyn type="dataFrame" property="time.date" format = "short"/>
```

For more information on dynamic text please see the following [link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/working-with-dynamic-text.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_702456ABD3D1487295B8FECA54D173B3)
which will give you the different options for formatting the date.

I have read the following on a page about time enabled text:

> If you have added time text in the data view, it shows up in the
>   layout view as well. To remove the time text added in the data view,
>   uncheck Show time on map display on the Time Display tab of the Time
>   Slider Options dialog box.

Please see the following link for more information:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/time/adding-time-text-to-the-display.htm